# Initializing EmbeddableDocumentStore fails

Tags: ravendb

[RavenDB 3.5.3 (Client, Database and Embedded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpD87.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore this. It is a debug only warning that has no impact and has to do with some calling convention issue